# Data Analysis on DataIku

Tags: database, dataiku

I have a Data Analysis on DataIku to do and I have to find the factor or factors that has an huge impact on weight fluctuations. I have a problem with that. I would be grateful if someone who is an expert in DataIku would help me.

I have an example where weight on 2023-08-31 T03:59:50.000Z is 1.49212492
but on 2023-08-31T03:59:55.000Z
is 1.36290312. So i see there is a huge fluctuation. How to identify the factor that affects this fluctuation among OMPENSATORY__POZ_KOMP_ZASIL_WYT_2_Value_min: A numerical variable related to compensation or supply.
KOMPENSATORY__POZ_KOMP_ZASIL_WYT_3_Value_min: Another numerical variable related to compensation or supply.
KOMPENSATORY__POZ_KOMP_ZASIL_WYT_4_Value_min: Yet another numerical variable related to compensation or supply.
LINIA_PRZED_UKLAD_CHLODZENIA__REC_WAGA_1M_AKT_Value_min: Numerical variable related to the weight on a cooling system.
TRANSPORTERY__PRED_ROLKI_SYNCHRO_Value_min: Numerical variable related to conveyor rollers.
TRANSPORTERY__PRED_TRAN_ODBIOR_Value_min: Numerical variable related to transport and delivery.
TRANSPORTERY__PRED_TRAN_ZAS_WYT_2_Value_min: Numerical variable related to transport and supply.
TRANSPORTERY__PRED_TRAN_ZAS_WYT_3_Value_min: Numerical variable related to transport and supply.
TRANSPORTERY__PRED_TRAN_ZAS_WYT_4_Value_min: Numerical variable related to transport and supply.
WYTLACZARKA_2__CIS_STRONA_LEWA_Value_min: Numerical variable related to extruder pressure on the left side.
WYTLACZARKA_2__CIS_STRONA_PRAWA_Value_min: Numerical variable related to extruder pressure on the right side.
WYTLACZARKA_2__PRAD_Value_min: Numerical variable related to extruder current.
WYTLACZARKA_2__PRED_OBROTOWA_Value_min: Numerical variable related to extruder rotational speed.
WYTLACZARKA_2__REC_PRED_OBROTOWA_Value_min: Numerical variable related to extruder rotational speed recording.
WYTLACZARKA_3__CIS_STRONA_LEWA_Value_min: Numerical variable related to another extruder's pressure on the left side.
WYTLACZARKA_3__CIS_STRONA_PRAWA_Value_min: Numerical variable related to another extruder's pressure on the right side.
WYTLACZARKA_3__PRAD_Value_min: Numerical variable related to another extruder's current.
WYTLACZARKA_3__PRED_OBROTOWA_Value_min: Numerical variable related to another extruder's rotational speed.
WYTLACZARKA_3__REC_PRED_OBROTOWA_Value_min: Numerical variable related to another extruder's rotational speed recording.
WYTLACZARKA_4__CIS_STRONA_LEWA_Value_min: Numerical variable related to yet another extruder's pressure on the left side.
WYTLACZARKA_4__CIS_STRONA_PRAWA_Value_min: Numerical variable related to yet another extruder's pressure on the right side.
WYTLACZARKA_4__PRAD_Value_min: Numerical variable related to yet another extruder's current.
WYTLACZARKA_4__PRED_OBROTOWA_Value_min: Numerical variable related to yet another extruder's rotational speed.
WYTLACZARKA_4__REC_PRED_OBROTOWA_Value_min: Numerical variable related to yet another extruder's rotational speed recording.
CBL: Numerical variable.
KM2: Numerical variable.
KM3: Numerical variable.
Categorical Variables:

Recepta: A categorical variable related to a recipe.
V_z_recepty: A categorical variable related to a recipe.

I don't know the best method